# Need help translating some sentences from Johannes Oecolampadius

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin, renaissance-latin

This is my first time posting here, so if my request is inappropriate or unwelcome, I apologize!

I recently completed a draft of a previously untranslated discourse by Johannes Oecolampadius on the Eucharist (*Sermo de sacramento eucharistiae*, 1521). There were a few sentences or phrases here and there that I could not quite decipher. I am wondering if anyone would be willing to help me translate them. It is very likely that the translation will be published, and you would of course get due acknowledgments in the final version.

I have uploaded all the various passages with screenshots of the original context to this Twitter thread:

https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1503135823843143681.html?fbclid=IwAR0PsgjdoLfCiJse0Ya838lL96TyUc3wB7ug-zOtSO-JD5QBTzxaMJEZxMI

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The sheer number of passages you're asking about here makes me think this question is too broad, as it stands.

Comment: Hi snemes2, I agree with Draconis that this question needs more focus. At StackExchange, questions do better when there's some specific answer that can be given. It operates a little bit differently from a discussion board. I'd recommend editing it to focus only on one aspect of your translation difficulties for now, and as that gets answered, more can be asked afterward.